# Relacionar facebook account a um aplicativo existente

Tags: android, facebook, unity3d

Bom dia,

Eu possuo um aplicativo android e recentemente resolvi iniciar sua campanha de marketing. Porem um dos primeiros passos é relacionar minha conta do facebook ao aplicativo e estou tendo problemas com isso.

Inicialmente ele aparece o meu aplicativo corretamente no checkbox, mas quando seleciono ele, ele muda o icone e fala que o aplicativo não está vinculado a minha conta.

Já gerei o facebook app id pelo facebook developers e relacionei no codigo fonte do meu aplicativo, é necessario alguma etapa alem dessa?

Estou usando Unity para desenvolver.

[image: selecionando aplicativo na facebook account]

Comment: tente registrar o app na sua conta de desenvolvedor primeiro

Comment: eu fiz isso, adicionei a plataforma, dominios e meu site. 
No unity coloquei o appid, mas ainda sim, estou com esse problema dele falar q as contas não estão relacionadas.